# How to create an invocation counter annotation in Spring?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc

Is it possible to create a custom annotation that simply tracks invocations of some methods, without having to add a service method call in every method explicit?

```
@InvocationCounter(path = "/test1") //I'm looking for this
@GetMapping("/person/{id}")
public Person getPerson(Long id) {
    //...
}
```

On every `getPerson()` call, I want an invocation counter to record the invocation, like:

```
@Service
public class InvocationCounterService {
      Map<String, AtomicInteger> counter;

      public void count(String path) {
          if (counter.get(path) == null) counter.put(path, new AtomicInteger()));
          counter.get(path).incrementAndGet();          
      }

      @Scheduled(fixedRate = 60000)
      public void persist() {
              //optionally process or persist the invocations
      }
}
```

Question: how could I possibly tell `Spring` to invoke the `count()` service method on each annotated controller method?

Comment: How about creating an Aspect to handle this scenario?

Comment: Could you give an example for aspect with this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The annotation **InvocationCounter**:

```
@Target(ElementType.METHOD)
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
public @interface InvocationCounter {
    String path();
}
```

The Aspect **InvocationCounterAspect**:

```
@Aspect
@Component
public class InvocationCounterAspect {

    @Autowired
    InvocationCounterService invocationCounterService;

    @Around("@annotation(InvocationCounter)")
    public Object logExecutionTime(ProceedingJoinPoint joinPoint) throws Throwable {
        MethodSignature signature = (MethodSignature) joinPoint.getSignature();
        InvocationCounter invocationCounter = signature.getMethod().getAnnotation(InvocationCounter.class);
        
        final String path = invocationCounter.path(); //retrieve path from the annotation

        invocationCounterService.count(path);  //call the counter service
        return joinPoint.proceed(); //proceed executing the annotated method
    }
}
```

Comment: Though `micrometer.io` might be an option, I prefer this solution instead of throwing an additional dependency in.

Answer (score 1):

You should be looking at `micrometer.io`,  Spring boot application natively supports metrics collection, including simple counter.

Answer (score 0):

*An annotation is a form of syntactic metadata that can be added to Java source code*.
So you can add informations to your source with an annotation but you can't add code to be executed.

You can do with aspects as mentioned by pleft in the comments.

Or you can create a countExecutions function that takes your Function as a lambda expression to count the number of executions as follow:

```
 public R countExecutions(Function<R, T> fun, T data) {
     // invoke counter
     return fun.apply(data);
 }
```

and rewriting your code as

```
@GetMapping("/person/{id}")
public Person getPerson(Long id) {
    return countExecutions( /* code previously in the getPerson as a Function */ , id);
}
```

Comment: Could you give an example for aspect with this?